# how to know file exist on server or not in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to know if a specific file exists a on server or not. For example, suppose I have an `.xml` file on my server and I want to know if the file is there or not through java from my android application.

Comment: U just want to check weather file exist or not ?

Answer (score 2):

What server is it? If its HTTP server, you can request that file and check from response if it exist. If its custom server you have to implement that feature yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
    URL url = null;
    URLConnection connection = null;
    InputStreamReader stream = null;

    // Parse the URL
    try {
        url = new URL(urlString);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        System.out.println("Malformed URL");
        return null;
    }

    // Open a connection to the URL
    try {
        connection = url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not create connection");
        return null;
    }

    // Get the remote file
    try {
        stream = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.printf("File \"%s\" does not exist!",urlString);
        return null;
    }
```